# SSRS Report Authentication working intermittently

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a requirement to generate a SSRS report server side from my MVC 6 controller and I'm currently playing around to try and get a stable solution. I'm experiencing that my c# code will successfully authenticate against my SSRS report server for some time and then all of a sudden it will give me `401 http` responses without any configuration or code changes, it's almost like I'm already authenticated and the connection is persisted and then after a certain period of time it will deny me. This morning when I started my test application again I authenticated and generated reports for a good 30 mines before I started getting 401 responses

Here is the setup of my `rsreportserver.config` file

```
<Authentication>
    <Extension Name="Windows" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Authentication.WindowsAuthentication, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Authorization"/>
</Authentication>

<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

and this is how I try to authenticate from c#, if there is a better way to do this please et me know

```
public async Task<byte[]> Generate
        (
        string reportServerUrl,
        string reportData,
        string username,
        string password
        )
    {
        var reportUrl = $@"{reportServerUrl}//ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx{reportData}";

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, $@"{reportUrl}/") })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(reportServerUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "NTLM");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var response = await client.GetAsync(reportUrl);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You could store a user credential in your app settings to use when running all reports, and manage the user data rights as a parameter on the reports when getting data. Also, have you tried adding the contract markup on the method for [Authenticate] to force the app to check to see if it has the credentials?

Comment: Hi, @Mmcgowa3, thank you for the reply. Do you have example code for the contract markup? I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: I miss spoke the mark up is actually called [Authorize] and you can use that mark up at the top of your controller class or on individual methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to render the report from my web application by making a normal HTTP post and passing the parameters together with my credentials to the report server. This method can certainly work for certain report server configurations but is not the correct way of rendering a SSRS report from C#. Microsoft already did all the hard work and provide a web service endpoint that can be used. The confusing part is that they actually provide 2 endpoints, each with it's own unique functions.

For a step-by-step article on how to do this, read my CodeProject article on [How to write a C# wrapper class for the SSRS report service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110411/How-to-Write-a-Csharp-Wrapper-Class-for-the-SSRS-R)

Below I give a quick guide to what I did

Add a web reference to

```
[Your report server host name]/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx
```

Now create a class that make use of the added web reference

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using SsrsWrapper.SsrsReportService;

namespace SsrsWrapper
{
    public class ReportManager
    {
        private readonly ReportExecutionService _reportServerExecutionService;

        public ReportManager(string reportServerWsdlUrl,string username,string password,string domain)
        {
            _reportServerExecutionService = new ReportExecutionService
            {
                Url = reportServerWsdlUrl,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
            };
        }

        public byte[] Render(string reportDirectory,string reportName,string reportFormat,ParameterValue[] parameters)
        {
            _reportServerExecutionService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();

            _reportServerExecutionService.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

            string encoding;
            string mimeType;
            string extension;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;

            var result = _reportServerExecutionService.Render(reportFormat, @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>", out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIds);

            return result;
        }

        public void Render(string reportDirectory,string reportName,string reportFormat,ParameterValue[] parameters,string destinationPath)
        {
            var result = Render(reportDirectory, reportName, reportFormat, parameters);

            var stream = File.Create(destinationPath, result.Length);

            stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the [Authorize] contract markup may solve your issue. See below:

```
[Authorize]
public class ReportController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult RunReport()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the Authorize attribute have nothing to do with the authentication to your Report Server, I have this filter enabled by default on all my controllers. The attribute is there to make sure anonymous browsers can't hit your controller without being authenticated. The c# code only gets called after this process succeeded.

Comment: What about the approach of using a static username and password for all reports, and then using a user id / name as a parameter input if you want to filter data by user?